# segmentation fault if deletion is done inside list iteration in c++

Tags: c++

```
list<abc*> mylist ;
for( it = mylist.begin() ; it != mylist.end() ; ++it ) {
    cout<<(*it)->getB()<<endl ;
    if(*it == "0x9090" )  {
         mylist.remove(*it);
    }
}
```

I inserted 4 abc class object in the list , when i remove / erase a element from list using some condition , it leads to segmentation fault in next iteration .

Answer (score 5):

Change the code to

```
list<abc*> mylist ;
for( it = mylist.begin() ; it != mylist.end() ;  ) {
    cout<<(*it)->getB()<<endl ;
    if(*it == "0x9090" )  {
         it = mylist.erase(*it);
    }
    else {
         ++it;
    }

}
```

I think you meant `erase` instead of `remove`. `remove` erases all elements in the list for which iterator i satisfy the condition *i = value where value in your case is *it

Also this statement

```
if(*it == "0x9090" )
```

is invalid. You are comparing two pointers that can be equal or enuequal depending on options of the compiler if `abc *` is equivalent to `char *`.

Maybe it is a typo and there should be

```
if(**it == "0x9090" )
```

Comment: @Dieter Lücking If you mean condition (*it == "0x9090" then I have pointed it in my post.

Comment: std::list::remove returns void

Comment: @Dieter Lücking Good remark. I even did not take into account that he uses remove instead of erase because it seems using remove has no sense for that loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should not iterate and remove (all list elements matching the value) - you might erase instead:

```
list<abc*> mylist ;
it = mylist.begin();
while(it != mylist.end()) {
    cout<<(*it)->getB()<<endl ;
    if(**it == "0x9090") it = mylist.erase(it);
    else ++it;
}
```